# Convert beamer presentation to Latex

Tags: presentations

I have some beamer presentations in the form of pdf files and I have to write the latex code that I lost. Is it possible with some tools?

Comment: (a pdf no longer has all the information from the tex file. While the tools in the linked post might help you to get the text etc, you'll probably have to manually have to redo all the formatting)

Comment: but it should be pretty mechanical the process... that's why i was asking

Comment: @gstfpp There are automated tools in the answers to the linked question, do check them out, but simple and mechanical for a human doesn't mean easy to automate. Specifying `beamer` doesn't particularly change the question: use something to scrape text or do a very rough conversion, then a good editor and some regex might help.  If there's a lot of structure to the PDF or something specific (potentially about using the `pdftotext` output say) maybe there's a separate question, but unfortunately the PDF having originally been made with latex doesn't help you much.